# Live boot from partition of USB (or just don't use up whole USB)

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

Is there a way to create a bootable USB stick that doesn't take up the whole disk? I have a 16GB USB but would like to also have some music on it.

Can it be partitioned or something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

All you have to do is use something like Unetbootin' to create the bootable flash drive, and then make a new folder on it and copy the extra data.

Comment: Assume for a minute I am using parted and `dd`

Comment: Then you should be able to use parted to create a partition, and then just copy your OS and install grup etc... and then add your extra data.

Comment: Do I need to install GRUB separately?

Comment: Depends on how you setup your bootable drive.  You may need to run `grub install /dev/sdX/`.  I recommend System Rescue and Unetbootin'.  [System Rescue CD](http://systemrescuecd.org) has ddrescue on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can can create partitions on your USB drive and make one partition to boot.

- Create two partitions on your usb drive and format both into fat32 filesystem.And don't forget to set the boot flag on the partition which you are trying to make bootable.I suggest you to go for Gparted partition Editor for doing partitioning.
- Copy all of your data to one partition.
- Now start unetbootin and select another partition of your USB drive to make it bootable.
- After the process completed, it prompts you to restart.
- Change the boot-order in bios to boot from the USB drive.Now it works.

Comment: And is it as simple as partitioning with parted and `dd`ing to that partition?

Comment: Use gparted partition editor.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will only see the first partition on a flash drive.
UNetbootin, etc, will only install to the first partition of a flash drive.
You can make a folder for music on that partition on a persistent install.

If you are doing a Full install to flash drive, you can make the first partition FAT32 or NTFS and use the second partition for / and the third for swap.
To do this use "Something else" while partitioning.
I can provide a step by step if you wish.